# Getting wrong file size for http file request

Tags: python, python-requests

So I am trying to fetch a 5 MB file from over the internet, via. http.

```
import requests
from tqdm import tqdm
def fetch_list():
    url = "http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/5MB.zip"

    # Streaming to facilitate response iteration
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)

    # Total size in bytes.
    total_size = (int(r.headers.get('content-length', 0)) / (32 * 1024))
    with open('5MB.zip', 'wb') as f:
        for data in tqdm(r.iter_content(32 * 1024), total=total_size, unit='B', unit_scale=True):
            f.write(data)
```

However, the problem with this code is that it doesn't show the correct file size and progress. The file is downloaded correctly though. Here is the progress bar shown below.

[image]

Where have I mistaken? Thanks!

Comment: print `len(data)` in loop. maybe you get differen sizes. did you check if total_size is correct? print it.

Comment: @furas output of `total_size` is definitely incorrect. But logically, this should be correct, shouldn't it. That's where I am stuck!